# npm is not working in the Windows Terminal

Tags: node.js, powershell, npm, git-bash, windows-terminal

I have currently installed the latest NodeJS (v19.9.0) through winget. Using it through Git Bash works just fine, however if I try using it through PowerShell or Windows Terminal the `node` command works just fine, but trying to use `npm` will result in the following error:

```
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1093
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js'
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1090:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:934:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:83:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}

Node.js v19.9.0
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1093
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js'
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1090:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:934:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:83:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}

Node.js v19.9.0
```

I have already tried reinstalling Node through the official website downloadable and also reinstall Windows Terminal/Powershell.
I also deleted temporary files and made sure that the Path Environmental Variable is configured correctly.

Comment: Error indicates code is looking for a main module.  See : https://mathieularose.com/main-function-in-node-js?force_isolation=true

Comment: Does the file `C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js` truly not exist (to rule out that the error is misleading)? Is directory path `C:\Program Files\nodejs` consistent with where `node.exe` is installed, as reported by `(Get-Command node).Path`?

Comment: @mklement0 It does seem that the path is wrong. The `node.exe` is truly in the `C:\Program Files\nodejs` path, however, the referenced `npm-cli.js` is simply under `C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin`. However this path is part of the SysEnv PATH .Can I change where the npm is looking for this file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**tl;dr**

**Remove the following directory from your persistent `Path` environment-variable definition** via the registry (run `sysdm.cpl`, go to the `Advanced` tab, and click on `Environment variables...`) or otherwise ensure that it doesn't end up as part of `$env:Path` in your PowerShell sessions:

```bash
C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin
```

***Only* `C:\Program Files\nodejs` should be in `$env:Path`**, which contains the proper CLI entry point, `npm.cmd`, alongside the Node.JS executable, `node.exe`x`

---

There are *multiple* `npm.cmd` files in the subtree of `C:\Program Files\nodejs`, and they all look for either `npm-cli.js` or `npm.js` in a location *relative to their own*.

`C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.cmd` and `C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node.cmd` are *identical* and use the following path to find the actual `.js` entry point, `npm-cli.js`, which is launched via `node.exe`:

```bash
SET "NPM_CLI_JS=%~dp0\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js"
```

That is, `npm-cli.js` is looked for in subfolder `.\node_modules\npm\bin` of the same directory in which `npm.cmd` is located.

This only works for `C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.cmd`, not for `C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node.cmd`, which ends up looking for
`C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js` - note the doubled `node_modules\npm\bin` part - which doesn't exist.

In your case, the mistaken `C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin` entry in `$env:Path` apparently comes *before* the proper `C:\Program Files\nodejs` entry, and therefore the wrong `npm.cmd` batch file executes
when you invoke a command with just `npm` (or `npm.cmd`).

Removing the mistaken entry should fix that problem.

In general, if the wrong executable is being invoked when you use a mere file name such as `npm`, use [`Get-Command`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/get-command) with the `-All` switch to show *all* such executables, in order of precedence: the one listed *first* is the *effective* one; e.g.:

```bash
# Print the full paths of all "npm" executables located in directories
# listed in $env:Path; the first one "wins".
Get-Command npm -All | ForEach-Object Path
```